# Does Google Wallet API for digital goods require an SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, android-pay

Going through the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial) for the Google Wallet API for digital goods, the need for an SSL certificate isn't mentioned. I searched around support articles and discussion boards and couldn't find any clear answer to this.

**Is an SSL certificate required (or recommended)** on a page that implements a 'buy' button to protect the credit card information entered by the user in the popup window, or is it **unnecessary** because that information is being sent to a secure Google domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your own question :-)

The Google Walet for digital goods transaction takes place in a secure popup on a Google domain. You can use a debugger (e.g. Firebug) to watch the network traffic (and see that it is HTTPS).