# Google Wallet - SSL / https handled completely by Google?

Tags: gwt, ssl, https, android-pay

For Google Wallet, I'm wondering if a SSL certificate for https needs to be setup on the serverside, or if all https access is done on Google's servers?

In the wallet tutorial, I notice that all https addresses are from google -

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSL certificate is not required on the server side. The postback call from Google mirrors back the original transaction data plus an order Id. If you are using the `sellerData` field, depending on your particular situation, you may consider encrypting that information.

Also see this related discussion:

[Does Google Wallet API for digital goods require an SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048562/does-google-wallet-api-for-digital-goods-require-an-ssl-certificate/18064157#18064157)